# How to upload files to Azure Blob storage from github using continuous integration

Tags: git, azure, continuous-deployment, azure-blob-storage

I am storing my scripts in Azure Blob storage. Right now, I am manually uploading each file to Blob storage when I do modify the files in git-hub branch.

I don't want to upload scripts manually when files get modified. Is there a way to push scrips from github to azure blob storage or any other methods?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Microsofts Visual Studio Team Services. It's free for 5 users and you get a Git Repo and a Build Pipeline. 
This couldbe the quickest solution to your problem. Otherwise, you probably would need to e.g. setup a build server or simple Azure Function, that deploys your files when triggered.

Comment: Is there any documentation regarding setup on Microsofts Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: Hi, it's a SaaS, so no installation. You access it via browser. That makes it so easy to use IMO.